# Does a magnet lose more potential when (passivley) magnetizing another metal?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, ferromagnetism

Does a magnet lose **more** of it's magnetic potential when (passively) magnetizing a second (ferromagnetic) metal compared with simply being left alone for the same amount of time it took?

Answer (score 0):

A magnet does not lose any of its magnetism when it magnetises another piece of metal. Well, it doesn't *necessarily* lose any of its magnetism.

The lowest energy state of a ferromagnet is to have all of its magnetic domains aligned. The reason pieces of e.g. iron generally aren't magnetised is because they are stuck in a local and the individual domains aren't free to rotate their fields into alignment with each other. So when you place your piece of unmagnetised iron near a permanent magnet it does not need to take energy from that magnet. Instead it will gradually settle into a magnetised state and release energy (i.e. get slightly hotter) as a result.

Incidentally the fact a material releases heat when it becomes magnetised can be used as a cooling method rather unoriginally called [magnetic refrigeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_refrigeration).